# crear una pausa antes de abrir ventana modal para que se carguen scripts

Tags: javascript

Estos scripts agregan formato especifico a una tabla, cuando la pagina es abierta por primera vez todo se muestra correctamente, pero visualizar el modal por segunda vez los archivos se cargan muy rapido y no se aplica sobre la tabla.

```
function salida()
{        
       $.ajax({
        url: '../reportes/cufinn',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
          data:{
            datos:'where estatus=0'
        },
    })
    .done(function(data) {

       for (i = 0; i <=data.length; i++) {
          if((i % 2)=== 0)
            {
            var c=' bgcolor= "#E0ECF8"';
            }
            else
            {
            var c='';
            }
           $("#datos1").append('<tr>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['ejercicio']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['periodo']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['Movimientoef'].toUpperCase()+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['Perdidaf']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['Perdidaa']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['Resultadof']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['PTUPP']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['PTUCC']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['ISRR']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['Nod']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['UFINN']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['difec']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['SaldosA']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['INPCMM']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['INPCFAA']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['Fact']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['SaldoAAc']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['Divp']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data[i]['SaldoTT']+'</td>'+
            '</tr>');
        }
    });  
   //alert("Cuin");
}

   function salida2()
       {        
        $.ajax({
        url: '../reportes/cufinn',
         type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
          data2:{
            datos:'where estatus=1'
        },
    })
    .done(function(data2) {

       for (i = 0; i <=data2.length; i++) {
          if((i % 2)=== 0)
            {
            var c=' bgcolor= "#E0ECF8"';
            }
            else
            {
            var c='';
            }
           $("#datos2").append('<tr>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['ejercicio']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['periodo']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['Movimientoef'].toUpperCase()+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['Perdidaf']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['Perdidaa']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['Resultadof']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['PTUPP']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['PTUCC']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['ISRR']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['Nod']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['UFINN']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['difec']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['SaldosA']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['INPCMM']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['INPCFAA']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['Fact']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['SaldoAAc']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['Divp']+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+data2[i]['SaldoTT']+'</td>'+
            '</tr>');
        }
    });  
    alert("Cuin");
}


        <script onload="salida()" src="<?php echo base_url("/_js/fixed_table_rc.js");?>" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script onload="salida2()" src="<?php echo base_url("/_js/fixed_table_rc2.js");?>" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url("/_js/build.js");?> "></script>
```

Comment: Si pones un poco mas de tu codigo quiza se nos haga un poco mas facil ayudarte

Comment: esas son las funciones que llenan mis tablas en la segunda tengo un alert, el cual permite que de tiempo al navegador de cargar los js en las tablas

Comment: Veo que estas mandando un 'where status=1' en un parametro POST, eso parece ser una falla de seguridad grave que deja tu sistema vulnerable a una inyeccion sql. Aparte de eso, estas usando dos veces la misma funcion, que es redundante y no le das uso a esa variable `var c`. Aparte de eso creo que podrias solucionar tu problema agregando una llamada a esas funciones dentro de los scripts que cargas, o usando un setTiemout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estoy en lo correcto es porque por default todas las solicitudes se realizan de forma asíncrona, si deseas que sea de forma sincronica la solicitud ajax debes cambiar el valor por default true a false en:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '../reportes/cufinn',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
          data:{
            datos:'where estatus=0'
        },
    })
```

Aqui puedes leer un poco más: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Si lees la documentación que enlazas, su uso está desaconsejado. Del mismo modo, el navegador te mostrará warnings desaconsejando su uso.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, tal ves este desaconsejado pero por el momento a solucionado mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que los dos scripts corren en el evento onLoad, como lo hiciste no habría forma de saber cual de los dos corrió primero. No creo que si pones en false el async funcione. Te dejo otra solución donde embebí los AJAX, en parámetro success ( no utilicé el método DONE)
Cuando termina la primera parte, inmediatamente corremos la segunda, así encadenamos el proceso.

```
//Función similar a onLoad
$(function() {

  //Primera llamada de AJAX
  $.ajax({
    url: '../reportes/cufinn',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      datos: 'where estatus=0'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //Callback del proceso 1
      for (i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        if ((i % 2) === 0) {
          var c = ' bgcolor= "#E0ECF8"';
        } else {
          var c = '';
        }
        $("#datos1").append('<tr>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['ejercicio'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['periodo'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['Movimientoef'].toUpperCase() + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['Perdidaf'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['Perdidaa'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['Resultadof'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['PTUPP'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['PTUCC'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['ISRR'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['Nod'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['UFINN'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['difec'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['SaldosA'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['INPCMM'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['INPCFAA'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['Fact'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['SaldoAAc'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['Divp'] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i]['SaldoTT'] + '</td>' +
          '</tr>');
      }

      //Segunda llamada AJAX dentro del callback del proceso 1
      $.ajax({
        url: '../reportes/cufinn',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data2: {
          datos: 'where estatus=1'
        },
        success: function(data2) {
          //Callback del proceso 2
          for (i = 0; i <= data2.length; i++) {
            if ((i % 2) === 0) {
              var c = ' bgcolor= "#E0ECF8"';
            } else {
              var c = '';
            }
            $("#datos2").append('<tr>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['ejercicio'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['periodo'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['Movimientoef'].toUpperCase() + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['Perdidaf'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['Perdidaa'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['Resultadof'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['PTUPP'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['PTUCC'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['ISRR'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['Nod'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['UFINN'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['difec'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['SaldosA'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['INPCMM'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['INPCFAA'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['Fact'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['SaldoAAc'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['Divp'] + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data2[i]['SaldoTT'] + '</td>' +
              '</tr>');
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Ya he intentado hacerlo así el detalle es que solo se cargan los datos de la primer tabla

Answer (score 0):

Si te he entendido bien creo que podrías solucionarlo utilizando [callbacks](http://anexsoft.com/p/112/javascript-que-son-como-usar-y-ejemplos-del-uso-de-callbacks). Esto es, enviar "salida2()" por parámetro a "salida()" para que se ejecute cuando esta última finalice.

Por ejemplo, tengo la función **"salida()"** que recibe por parámetro una función. La función **"salida()"** hace una llamada asíncrona y una vez finalizada, ejecuta **callback()**.

```
function salida(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'someurl',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            // json data
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // do something

            if (typeof(callback) === 'function')
                callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Ahora, la forma de llamar a esta función sería:

```
salida(function(){
    // do something after execute
});
```

o también:

```
function salida2() {
    // do something
}

salida(salida2);
```